# Redirect the person, who has already seen the page

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect, cookies

I am looking for help for the following scenario:

I have a website1.com. I would like website1.com to be like a presentation page. I want every person who has seen the page to be redirected automatically to website2.com.

Another way to look at it:

Lets say the page on website1.com contains information, which would be irrelevant for the person, who has already seen it, therefore I want them to be redirect from the page to website2.com cause then i don't loose the visitor, since I own both of those sites.

From the prespective of the visitor:

I land on a website, which I have not visited yet, website1.com. However, if I have already been to website1.com in the past ( cookie registers it ) , then i am redirected to website2.com

Hope how i broke it down is clear for everybody.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Imagine how real frustrating would it be for a person who (for whatever reason) wants to see the page1 again...

Comment: .... maybe i dont want them to see the page again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PHP, you could do it that way at the begining of your page:

```
 <?php 
     if (!isset($_COOKIE['myCookie'])){
        setcookie('myCookie', true, time() + (86400 * 30));
     }
     else{
       header('Location: http://www.website2.com');
     }
 ?>
```

If you are not using PHP, your serverside language surely have a way to set cookie and the logic will be the same. Hope it helped

Comment: the presentation page is simply based in html, however the server does support php..so if i add this code and change the html extension to .php it would ideally work?

Comment: Yes it would ! just change it to index.php

Comment: It will set a cookie for 30 days tho, so if you want to test properly, i'd suggest you to change the value to time() + 60 to set the cookie for 1 minute while testing